# Cumulative distribution function of a continuous uniform random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

I know that the CDF of a continuous uniform (over $[a,b]$) random variable is:

\begin{align}
CDF_X(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } t < a \\
\frac{t - a}{b - a} &\text{if } a \leq t < b \\
1 &\text{if } t \geq b
\end{cases}
\end{align}

To get this result, is it ok to evaluate the 3 integrals below?

\begin{align}
CDF_X(t) =
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq a}} 0 \, dt = 0 \\
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq b}} f(t) \, dt =
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq a}} 0 \, dt +
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{a}^{t \leq b}} \frac{1}{b - a} \, dt = \frac{t - a}{b - a} \\
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq + \infty}} f(t) \, dt =
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq a}} 0 \, dt +
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{a}^{b}} \frac{1}{b - a} \, dt +
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{b}^{t \leq + \infty}} 0 \, dt
= 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, it’s correct.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei thank you

Comment: IMHO, this task puts the relation between PDF, CDF, and intuitive definition of the distribution backwards. The CDF can also be obtained directly from the definition of uniform distribution as: The probability of $X\in$ some subinterval of $[a,b]$ depends *only* on the length of said interval. (After all, the piecewise constance of the PDF is by itself also only a consequence of that definition, and the specific value of the constant is only motivated by the goal of making $CDF(b)=1$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you show the alternative way to get it please?